# MySql, after DELETE update a counter to contain no gaps

Tags: mysql, sql-update, delete-row

I have a mySql table like this (simplified)

```
Id*| Text |  Pos (integer)
-----------
A  | foo  |  0
B  | bar  |  1
C  | baz  |  2
D  | qux  |  3
```

Now, after I delete a row, I want to update the Pos value on the remaining rows so that no "holes" or gaps are to be found.

For example if I row with Id='C' is deleted, the remaing table should be:

```
Id*| Text |  Pos (integer)
-----------
A  | foo  |  0
B  | bar  |  1
D  | qux  |  2
```

Is this possible in a single query?

**UPDATE**
Based on the accepted answer this was the solution to my problem:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=pos FROM table_name WHERE Id= 'C';
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE Id = 'C';
UPDATE table_name SET Pos = Pos - 1 WHERE Pos > @A;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a [AFTER DELETE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) on table,

or by using transactions:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT Pos 
INTO @var_pos
FROM table_name
WHERE id = 'C';

DELETE 
FROM table_name
WHERE id = 'C';

UPDATE table_name
SET Pos = Pos - 1
WHERE Pos > @var_pos;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I want. Just not working in my case as the ID is not ordered (its a random string)

Comment: You're welcome! You just need to add `ORDER BY id ASC` in your `UPDATE` query. Try updated answer.

Comment: But still, as you use "id > 'C'" and id is not ordered it is not working.

Comment: Ok. this might be happening because of `VARCHAR` data type of field `id`. Please try updated query.

Comment: Brilliant thank you / you showed me the way. Your answer was not working, threw an error: You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause. I have updated my question with a workable solution based on your answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work, (I haven't tested it)
you can run this statement after any delete

```
update t set t.Pos=a.iterator
from tablename t 
join(
     SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS iterator, t.id
     FROM tablename t,(SELECT @i:=0) r)a
on a.id=t.id
```